# NHibernate: How to call a stored procedure and Single/Plural for models?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Can anyone tell me the best and recommended way of calling a stored procedure using NHibernate?

I have my mappings set up and currently i have this working

```
 var list = session.CreateSQLQuery("exec usp_Test").AddEntity(typeof(Product)).List<Product>();
```

And sure enough i am getting a LIST back of my products, but is this the best way of doing this?

Also are the Model classes ie. Product best set as Singular or Plural (Products).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to avoid stored procedures with NHibernate whenever possible.

There might be still reasons to use stored procedures. Is so, there are several ways to use them with NHibernate.

Call them directly as a query (as you do), specify them as predefined query or you could even define them as the way how NHibernate should select, insert or update an entity.

There is a [post from Ayende](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/09/18/UsingNHibernateWithStoredProcedures.aspx) how to use stored procedures in mapping files.

There is a [post on Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/Execute_SQL_Nhibernate.aspx) how to call them from the code.

About your code:

- `AddEntity` does not add a type, but an entity instance. It is actually turned to its primary key.
- The stored procedure can't really provide a list of Products. Only NHibernate, the ORM, is able to read objects from the database. When you call a stored procedure, you directly go to the database.

I don't understand the last sentence about singular and plural. Is this another question?

Comment: Thank you! Yes with regards to single or plural.. My entity classes that i created (which the mapping files point to) are currently singular i.e PRODUCT (no s) i presume this is the recommended way or should the entities been PLURAL i.e. PRODUCTS (notice the s)

Comment: @Martin: Classes are always in singular, plural would mean that it is a container or collection type. Table names are usually plural, but personally, I break with that tradition and call the tables the same as the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Typically if you're using nHibernate you allow it to generate queries for you. Not that there's anything wrong with what you're doing but you're cheating yourself out of some of the usefulness of nHibernate by doing it this way. If I were you I'd look into gathering objects through the use of criteria objects instead.